# Failure of Unique Factorization into Primes

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, prime-numbers

> Show that in the domain of integers in the form $a+b\sqrt{-17}$ unique factorization into primes fails.

It was given that $169=13\bullet 13=(4+3\sqrt{-17})(4-3\sqrt{-17})$. This is an example that falls into the required domain.

In order for unique factorization into primes to fail, it needs to be shown that $(4+3\sqrt{-17})(4-3\sqrt{-17})$ is not prime - meaning it is irreducible.

If it is irreducible, then it cannot be factored into two other integers in that domain.

The norm of $(4+3\sqrt{-17})$ is $25$. What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the norm of $4 + 3\sqrt{-17}$ is $169 = 13^2$. But anyway, if it had a nontrivial factorization, say $4 + 3\sqrt{-17} = \alpha\beta$, then by multiplicativity of norms you would have:

$$N(\alpha)N(\beta) = 13^2$$

Which means that $N(\alpha) = \pm 13$ (since otherwise $\alpha$ or $\beta$ would have unit norm and would have to be a unit). Remember that $\alpha$ must be of the form $\alpha = x + y\sqrt{-17}$ for some integers $x, y$.

But there are no integers $x, y$ such that $x^2 + 17y^2 = \pm 13$.

Comment: How did you get $13^2$?

Comment: In general, the norm of $x + y\sqrt{-17}$ is $x^2 + 17y^2$. When $x = 4$ and $y = 3$, this is $4^2 + 17\cdot 3^2 = 169$. In fact, that is exactly what you were given with the factorization of $13^2 = (4 + 3\sqrt{-17})(4 - 3\sqrt{-17})$.

Comment: Why then do they give both $(4 + 3\sqrt{-17})$ and $(4 - 3\sqrt{-17})$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The norm can also be defined (in this case, at least) as the product of all conjugates. The conjugates of $4 + 3\sqrt{-17}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17})$ are $4 \pm 3\sqrt{-17}$.

Comment: If the norm of $4+3\sqrt{-17}$ is 13*13, whey then do we have both conjugates. How is the norm the same?

Comment: I realize I must be missing something basic here...

Comment: The norm of $4 + 3\sqrt{-17}$ is the same as the norm of $4 - 3\sqrt{-17}$. In general, the norms of any two conjugates are the same. Is that what you were asking about?